# How can I track volume of sound in Twilio call?

Tags: android, twilio

I’m using Twilio Android API to perform a VoIP call between two Android clients. Is it possible to track the current volume of the call?

The need for such possibility comes from the following use case: I want to request audio focus only when another party is talking and abandon it as soon as the silence is detected on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I can see in the [Android Programmable Voice documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/voice/releases/2.0.9/docs/), there is no access to the audio stream in order to track the volume of the call.

This is likely something you could achieve if you were making audio calls between apps using the [Twilio Video SDK for Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/android). (And if you are only making app to app calls, then sound quality will be better too as it's not downsampled for the phone network.)

Comment: I've started looking at Video SDK, however I can not find any option, that allows tracking the volume/detecting the silence. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should be able to get access to the media stream itself and then work with the audio from that. There is also info on detecting the dominant speaker here which might help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/detecting-dominant-speaker